# What's the difference between if( $x=1 || $y=1) and if( $x=1 | $y=1) in PHP

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Whats the difference between these two in php?

```
 if( $x==1 || $y==1)   if( $x==1 && $y==1)
```

vs. (respectively)

```
 if( $x==1 | $y==1)    if( $x==1 & $y==1)
```

To my knowledge they both work the same | vs. || in php. But there has to be a difference!!!

Comment: Do you mean `=` (assignment) or `==` (comparison)?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee i mean == (comparison)... I fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`||` and `&&` are boolean operators, they take 2 arguments, convert each to a boolean, then return `true` or `false`.

`|` and `&` are *bitwise* operators.  They convert their arguments to *binary* and compare each bit.  They return a binary number.

Comment: clear and concise! perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @Arian, also note that `||` and `&&` evaluate their arguments from left-to-right and short-circuit as soon as possible, that is, if the left expression is true, `||` will not evaluate anything to the right (same for false and `&&`).

Answer (score 2):

One is using conditional *or* and *and* and the other is using bitwise *or* and *and*.

Answer (score 1):

`||` this is condition `OR` 
`|` this is bit wise `or`

1. `$a | $b`   `Or` (inclusive or)     Bits that are set in either `$a` or `$b` are set
2. `$a & $b`   `And`   Bits that are set in both `$a` and `$b` are set.

.

```
              if( $x==1 || $y=1)             if( $x==1 && $y==1)

  if body --> if one of them is true            both is true
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: `if( $x=1 || $y=1)` will set $x to the value of 1 and $y to the value of 1.

The correct syntax would be:

`if( $x==1 || $y==1)`

The difference can be better expressed with words:

`if( $x==1 OR $y==1)` `` `if( $x==1 AND $y==1) ``

The double ampersand and double pipes are known as logical operators. [see more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

The single ampersand and single pipes are bitwise statements. [see more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: It is valid syntax; the statement `$x=1` returns 1 (assigns 1 to `$x`) and likewise with `$y`, and these are then bitwise OR or bitwise AND together.

Comment: which is what i stated in the first sentence

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your last sentence, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your friend. `&&` and `||` are logical operators. You can read more about them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

I highly suggest you read about [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and learn why `&&` vs `and` and `||` vs `or` are different. Learn when one is more appropriate than the other. Essentially `=` has higher precedence than `and` and `or`, but lower precedence than `&&` and `||`. Example #1 of the [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) section does a good job of explaining this.

With other languages you just have `&&` and `||`, not `and` and `or`.

`&` and `|` are bitwise operators. You can read about them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Typical usage for bitwise operators are flags. One common use is PHP's [error_reporting setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).